# Simulation test of public method taking integers arguments fails with errorcode "WasmUnknownError"

Tags: nearprotocol, assemblyscript

The problem occurs when using the command "near-vm" to execute a simulation test of an assemblyscript smart contract method that takes inputs of type numbers like i32, u32, i64, u64. The following error is returned "FunctionCallError":"WasmUnknownError".

**How to reproduce:**

1. git clone the https://github.com/Learn-NEAR/starter--near-sdk-as
2. Build (`yarn`) and Run test (`yarn test`). Everything should works well
3. Now add simple public method to add to numbers  in `src/simple/assembly/index.ts`

```
export function add(a: i32, b: i32): i32 {
  return a + b;
}
```

4. Optionally you can also add a corresponding unit test `src/simple/__tests__/index.unit.spec.ts` and it will pass successfully

```
it("should return the sum of two integers", () => {
    const sum = add(1, 2);

    expect(sum).toBe(3);
 })
```

4. Now the problem occurs when running simulation test using near-vm

```
yarn near-vm --wasm-file build/debug/simple.wasm --method-name add --input '{"a": 1, "b": :2}
```

Then you get "FunctionCallError":"WasmUnknownError"

```
{"outcome"{"balance":"10000000000000000000000000",
"storage_usage":100,"return_data":"None","burnt_gas":39848843793,"used_gas":39848843793,"logs":[]},
"err":{"FunctionCallError":"WasmUnknownError"},"receipts":[],"state":{}}
```

Note that this problem doesn't occur when the method parameters are strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the simulation tests there are outdated and need to be updated

Check out this new way of simulating NEAR contracts

https://github.com/near/workspaces-js

Comment: Interesting and straightforward to write tests :)  ... 
However after writing the ava test for the simple sum method, 
I get the following error when arguments are of type number ..... 
(The test works well with strings arguments).
    ```kind: {
      ExecutionError: 'WebAssembly trap: Stack overflow.',
    },
    message: '{"index":0,"kind":{"ExecutionError":"WebAssembly trap: Stack overflow."}}.  Object.parseResultError (node_modules/near-api-js/lib/utils/rpc_errors.js:31:29)
  › Account.signAndSendTransactionV2 (node_modules/near-api-js/lib/account.js:160:36)
  ```